# Seeding rails database results in the same Post being created twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just trying to seed these coordinates, however it is creating two exact duplicates of each post record. So Post id 1 - 12 looks good but it repeats 13 - 24. I can't figure out why. I believe the code is ok but maybe I'm overlooking something. Does anyone see an error or better way to do this.

```
coordinates = {
  Albany: [42.40,   73.45],
  Albuquerque: [35.05, 106.39],
  Amarillo: [35.11, 101.50],
  Anchorage: [61.13, 149.54],
  Atlanta: [33.45, 84.23],
  Austin: [30.16,   97.44],
  Baker: [44.47, 117.50],
  Baltimore: [39.18, 76.38],
  Bangor: [44.48, 68.47],
  Birmingham: [33.30, 86.50],
  Bismarck: [46.48, 100.47],
  Boise: [43.36, 116.13]
}

image = #path to image

coordinates.values.each do |coordinate|
  Post.create(latitude: coordinate[0], longitude: coordinate[1], image: image)
end
```

And the console

```
[1] pry(main)> Post.all
  Post Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
=> [#<Post id: 1, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e901360,'0.424E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e900e10,'0.7345E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 2, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9127f0,'0.3505E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e911c88,'0.10639E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 3, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e91bf30,'0.3511E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e91bcd8,'0.1015E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 4, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e91a748,'0.6113E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e91a4f0,'0.14954E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "
 #<Post id: 5, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e919398,'0.3345E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e919140,'0.8423E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 6, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e923c30,'0.3016E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9239d8,'0.9744E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 7, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e922420,'0.4447E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9220d8,'0.1175E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 8, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9207d8,'0.3918E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e920490,'0.7638E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 9, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e92aff8,'0.4448E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e92ad78,'0.6847E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 10, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e929b80,'0.333E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e929950,'0.865E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 11, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e928758,'0.4648E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9284d8,'0.10047E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 12, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9331f8,'0.4336E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e932f78,'0.11613E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:37", image: "apple_icon.png">,

#### starts repeating at 13

 #<Post id: 13, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e931d58,'0.424E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e931b28,'0.7345E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 14, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e93bda8,'0.3505E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e93b9c0,'0.10639E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 15, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9382c0,'0.3511E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e943c60,'0.1015E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 16, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9429c8,'0.6113E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9426f8,'0.14954E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 17, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e940790,'0.3345E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e940268,'0.8423E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 18, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e94a2b8,'0.3016E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e949e30,'0.9744E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 19, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e953c00,'0.4447E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9539d0,'0.1175E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 20, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e952238,'0.3918E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e951a90,'0.7638E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 21, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e95b6a8,'0.4448E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e95b388,'0.6847E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 22, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e95a140,'0.333E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e959ee8,'0.865E2',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 23, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e958cf0,'0.4648E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e958a70,'0.10047E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">,
 #<Post id: 24, latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e963740,'0.4336E2',18(45)>, longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fc80e9634c0,'0.11613E3',18(45)>, created_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", updated_at: "2013-11-02 21:19:44", image: "apple_icon.png">]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you done two times **rake db:seed** ?

If yes, it two times create the same items.

When you run seed it doesn't remove records, if you want to do this put

```
Post.destroy_all
```

above coordinates.

Do I answer you for question?

Comment: wow that's interesting. I usually create a rake task to seed the db instead of using `db/seeds.rb`. I was using `Rake db:reset` to drop the data like I usually do and didn't realize it doesn't work for `seeds.rb`. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome :)

You should use db/seeds.rb file and rake db:seed to load. You don't need any custom rake :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put the create call in a condition:

```
coordinates.values.each do |coordinate|
  if Post.where( latitude: coordinate[0], longitude: coordinate[1] ).empty?
    Post.create(latitude: coordinate[0], longitude: coordinate[1], image: image)
  end
end
```

This way you can run rake db:seed and not get repeats.

Check out [find_or_create_by](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)